# Google App Engine Error - in check_initialized raise MissingRecipientsError()

Tags: python, google-app-engine, contact-form

I'm trying to setup a static webpage on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) with a contact-form. I originally used php but it doesn't work with GCP. In my research,[LINK](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/71761-googles-app-engine-email-sending/), I tried using the provided code and got the following error:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Leave a message</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
  <input name="mail" placeholder="Enter your email">
<br/>
<input name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
<br/>
<input name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
<br/>
<textarea name="message" style="height:200px; width:500px;" placeholder="Enter your message">
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>


</body>
</html>
```

```
INFO     2018-01-26 11:17:08,904 module.py:833] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 2317
  File "F:\Programs\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Documents\Programming\html\perrykowebdesigns2\contact.py", line 48, in post
    message.send()
  File "F:\Programs\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 1129, in send
    message = self.ToProto()
  File "F:\Programs\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 1385, in ToProto
    message = super(EmailMessage, self).ToProto()
  File "F:\Programs\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 1067, in ToProto
    self.check_initialized()
  File "F:\Programs\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 1370, in check_initialized
    raise MissingRecipientsError()
MissingRecipientsError
```

I'm relatively new, so I don't understand the error and how to fix it. If you understand how to fix it, please provide the solution.

Thanks!

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
from google.appengine.api
import mail

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
    autoescape = True)



class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, * a, * * kw):
    self.response.out.write( * a, * * kw)

def render_str(self, template, * * params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
return t.render(params)

def render(self, template, * * kw):`enter code here`
    self.write(self.render_str(template, * * kw))

class contact(Handler):
    def get(self):
    self.render("contact.html")

# template = jinja_env.get_template('contact.html')# def get(self): #self.response.out.write(self.template.render())
def post(self): #takes input from user
userMail = self.request.get("mail")
subject = self.request.get("subject")
name = self.request.get("name")
userMessage = self.request.get("message")
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = "7dayclimber@gmail.com", subject = "Test")

# not tested
if not mail.is_email_valid(userMail):
    self.response.out.write("Wrong email! Check again!")
message.to = userMail
message.body = ""
"Thank you!
You have entered following information:
    Your mail: % s
Subject: % s
Name: % s
Message: % s ""
" %(userMail,subject,name,userMessage)
message
self.response.out.write("Message sent!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', contact)], debug = True)
```

Comment: `MissingRecipientsError` - looks like you're missing the recipient. But you need to provide the related `contact.py` code for specifics.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've posted my python code above.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `to` argument in the `mail.EmailMessage()` call.

From [google.appengine.api.mail module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.mail):

> An EmailMessage can be built completely by the constructor:
>
> ```
> EmailMessage(sender='sender@nowhere.com',
>              to='recipient@nowhere.com',
>              subject='a subject',
>              body='This is an email to you').Send()
> ```

Comment: Make sure you're using an authorized email account; this mostly has to be a gmail account. This can be done in the GAE settings, email sender section.

Comment: Yeah, that's documented as well: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api#before_you_begin